# Extra white spaces automatically disabled in PhP: why?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, safari, trim

I was trying to use the trim() function on my $_POST variable for a form I just created, but noticed there was no use as the extra white spaces are automatically disabled.

I created a very simple PhP form (form.php) asking a name to the user. Then I have in my target.php (page where the data is processed) something like this:

```
<p>Hello <?php echo $_POST['nickname'];?>, how are you today?</p>
```

The fact is that even if the user enter as a name "     Peter     ", I see this in Safari and Chrome : "Hello Peter, how are you today?"... Without using the trim() function !

So here is my question : are the modern browser automatically trimming the end result?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: press ctrl+u and check what you get? there  is not any browser functionality

Comment: I can see the extra spaces when I display the sources but was wondering why they did not appear when I display the result in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an functionality but the browser is not showing the space 
I have tried with the below code

```
$text = 'john ';
$text[10] = 'doe';
print_r($text);exit;
```

You will see john d in the output even though there is a space at the end of john

Try viewing the source and you will see something different

Comment: Yes, true. Indeed when i display the source I can see the extra spaces. But can you tell me how and why the browser is not showing the extra spaces by default? Thank you!

Comment: @PierreGiraud thanks if the answer satisfied you please accept the answer so the question will not be in the open state